# Table styling is not reflecting/replicating dynamically in Nintex generated Document in Salesforc

Tags: excel, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, nintex-workflow

I have to create a table in excel using Nintex DocGen.

There are styling and conditions that needs to be there in the table.
Main things I want is:

1. Keeping the table row height fixed: Which I am able to by keeping the row height of the whole document fixed to the required height, since when we genrate the document using DocGen, any number of rows could be populated.
2. Conditional coloring of cell: This one also I am able to do by applying the condition to a large range
3. Alternate row coloring in the table: This is really giving me the problem because this is the one thing needs to applied up until the generated row in the table. Here if I make the alternate coloring to a fixed number of rows then there would be an issue of over alternate coloring or under.

Also, I am not able to find any official document for table styling in Excel for Nintex DocGen.

Any help would be appreciated.

Let me know anything else is required.

Thanks

Image, just for reference:
[image: Image just for reference]